# Unable to view Worddocument/pdf inside the Windowsstore app8.1

Tags: c#

My windows8.1 store app needs to open word Document and pdf file in read only format from the customized path folder not in Assest.
Code below

```
Encoding utf8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(true, true);
            StorageFolder storagefolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile storagefile = await storagefolder.GetFileAsync(@"C:\sampledoc\sample_raw.txt");
            var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions() { DisplayApplicationPicker = true };
            await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(storagefile, options);
```

While running the the above code getting below mentioned Errors

*An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007B)*

Comment: Not trying to sound like a jerk, but 99% of the time this error message means exactly what it says.  The file you think is there is not, or you don't have permission to it.